# Asyncsocket iPhone read data

Tags: ios, iphone, asyncsocket

I'm trying to catch a response from a .NET server using the following code.

Doing a telnet test works (I get the response); but, using this code, I don't get a response.

```
-(IBAction)connectClicked:(id)sender {
    if (![socket connectToHost:@"192.168.100.192" onPort:1337 error:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"connection failed");
    }    
}

-(IBAction)fireClicked:(id)sender {
    NSString *welcomeMsg = @"GetId";
    NSData *welcomeData = [welcomeMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [socket writeData:welcomeData withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    NSLog(@"message sent!");
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString*)host port:(UInt16)port {
    NSLog(@"onSocket:%p didConnectToHost:%@ port:%hu", sock, host, port);
    [sock readDataToData:[AsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

-(void) onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData*)data withTag:(long)tag {
    NSLog(@"onSocket:%p didReadData:%i", tag);    
    [sock readDataToData:[AsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}

- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didWriteDataWithTag:(long)tag {
    NSLog(@"onSocket:didWriteDataWithTag:%i", tag);    
    [sock readDataToData:[AsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
```

I do get the connection with the server and I'm able to send information to the server, but I do not get a reply.

This is what I get in the logging;

```
2011-03-21 10:00:32.424 CtC[33521:207] onSocket:0x4c3ebc0 didConnectToHost:192.168.100.192 port:1337
2011-03-21 10:00:35.846 CtC[33521:207] message sent!
```

Why am I not receiving a reply?

Answer (score 2):

i also have the same problem. i simulated the 'enter' button when write data since the server don't know when the command ended.

So this line

```
NSString *welcomeMsg = @"GetId";
```

should become

```
NSString *welcomeMsg = @"GetId\r\n";
```

It worked now.

Comment: @derk try implement `- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sender willDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error`

Comment: i just read your comment on andy.. try to change this `[sock readDataToData:[AsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:-1 tag:0];` to `[sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];`

Comment: hi Suprie, the error i get is; `Error 3 (Read operation timed out)`

Comment: Maybe you set the timeout to low. I dont know what happened, but everytime i set the timeout to 0 those error was raised. So i always use 100 or -1 for timeout.

Comment: To know, if my programme was going fine, i tried to connect to common local server - like ftp - and tried to read some response from them. If its worked to ftp, it should work on other services.

Comment: @suprie ... i use the -1 for timeout, also 1000 for timeout raises the Read operation timed out... do you have a snippet code for some basic interaction?

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on what could go wrong because the code snippet is not enough. But that is how I would go on:

1. Check that when you connect to the host that it does not raise an error
2. In you fireClicked method make sure that socket is properly initiated
3. Maybe override didConnectToHost method and add a NSLog statement to see if you connected
4. Use the given socket "sock" inside didReadData and didWriteDataWithTag instead of the variable "socket"
5. Tell us what logging statements you get
6. Tell us how you created the socket and how you connected to the host.

Hope that helps - Andy

Comment: hi andy! thanks for you anwser! - i updated my question... but it still doesn't work... can you perhaps take a look? thanks!

Comment: As Suprie mentioned you must make sure that the server side knows when you incoming call ends (Enter, CTRL-D etc). Otherwise the .Net server might just sitting there and wait for further input.

Comment: 4. Was the solution to my issue. Oversight. Thanks @Andy S.

Answer (score 0):

WireShark is always useful in these situations.  A quick comparison between telnet and your app might indicate a difference.

Try removing the 'readDataWithTimeout' that you have in the didConnectToHost, since you call this after a write anyway.
I'm wondering if you are getting a disconnect which is causing the timeout on the read, ie your wire protocol is wrong.  WireShark should help there.